# Zurb Foundation: Slider plugin doesn't fire events when imported as ES module

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, es6-modules

I'm trying to use only ES modules on my site and currently have the issue with Zurb Foundation. I use [Skypack](https://skypack.dev) to import ES modules and don't use any bundlers.

When I place some classic init code on the page, events from slider fires as expected:

```html
<!-- Basic slider template. See https://get.foundation/sites/docs/slider.html -->
<div id="test-slider" class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="30" data-end="100">
  <span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1"></span>
  <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.6.3/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.6.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // Init Foundation
    //Foundation.addToJquery($);
    $(document).foundation();

    $('#test-slider').on('moved.zf.slider', function() {
      console.log('This should work while slider slides!');
      //console.log($._data($('#test-slider')[0]).events);
    });

  });
</script>
```

But when I convert code above into ES Module, slider events stops working:

```html
<h4>Drag the slider</h4>

<!-- Basic slider template. See https://get.foundation/sites/docs/slider.html -->
<div id="test-slider" class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="30" data-end="100">
  <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1"></span>
  <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>

<h4>Expected</h4>
<p>Drag slider and console should populated with <strong>'This should work while slider slides!'</strong> message.</p>
<h4>Current</h4>
<p>Drag slider and console shows nothing.</p>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.skypack.dev/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.css">

<script type="module">
  
  import $ from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery?min'; // Latest jQuery from skypack.dev
  import { Foundation } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/foundation-sites?min'; // Latest Foundation from skypack.dev
   
  $(document).ready(function() {
    
    Foundation.addToJquery($);
    $(document).foundation();
    
    $('#test-slider').on('moved.zf.slider', function () {
      console.log('This should work while slider slides!');
      //console.log($._data($('#test-slider')[0]).events);
    });
    
    // This will work because it is natural jQuery event, not the one from Foundation
    //$('#test-slider').on('click', function () {
    //   console.log('Click works!');
    //});
  });
</script>
```

What I'm missing? And how can it be fixed?

Demo Codepen with problematic code is [**here!**](https://codepen.io/cmdeviant/pen/yLgwmpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I found what cause the issue with events.

In time when the question was posted the `foundation-sites` module import uses the latest version of Zurb Foundation (v6.6.3) and that version was compiled with jQuery v3.5.1 import internally. It can be checked by following urls inside https://cdn.skypack.dev/foundation-sites and inspecting the code.

But in the question's code example I use `import $ from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery?min'` which imports the latest jQuery version (v3.6.0)

Because I import jQuery v3.6.0 and Foundation module uses jQuery v3.5.1 internally, the event listener was placed in the **different scope** (some kind of) which differs from scope of Slider or any of Zurb Foundation UI elements, fix me if I'm wrong here.

### Option 1.

So the solution is to stick with certain versions of modules to get 'match' with internal jQuery version of `foundation-sites` module.

Replace this:

```
import $ from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery?min'; // Latest jQuery from skypack.dev
import { Foundation } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/foundation-sites?min'; // Latest Foundation from skypack.dev
```

With this:

```
import $ from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery@3.5.1?min'; // jQuery v3.5.1 from skypack.dev
import { Foundation } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/foundation-sites@6.6.3?min'; // Foundation v6.6.3 from skypack.dev
```

### Option 2.

In case someone has the same issue but didn't want to 'stick' with certain version of jQuery.

When Foundation wraps the element it adds `jQuery{version}{some-kind-of-timestamp}` properties to that element. Like so:

[image: Element's specific properties when it was initialised with Foundation]

Two properties which names started with `jQuery3510` were added by Foundation. One of them contains `events` property. But as we uses another jQuery version imported from different ES module there is another one `jQuery3600` with `events`. And when I do

```
$('#test-slider').on('moved.zf.slider', function () {
   // Do something
});
```

the registration of `moved.zf.slider` event goes into `jQuery3600`, not into `jQuery3510` as it should.

So the solution here is to update `jQuery3510` which contains `events` with events from `jQuery3600`. I extend jQuery with function that does this:

```
$.fn.mutatedOn = function (events, callback) {

    function getPropsByName(obj, startWith) {
        return Object.keys(obj).filter((propertyName) => {
            return propertyName.indexOf(startWith) === 0;
        });
    }

    function findPropsWithEvents(obj) {
        const props = getPropsByName(obj, "jQuery");
        return props.find((element) => {
            return obj[element].events !== undefined;
        });
    }

    $(this).each((index, el) => {

        // Let's find all properties which starts with 'jQuery'.
        // And filter them to determine those which contains 'events'
        // right before we attach the event listener.
        const jqueryKeys = getPropsByName(el, "jQuery");
        const jqueryKeysWithEvents = findPropsWithEvents(el);

        $(el).on(events, callback);

        // After the listener attached, another 'jQuery' property with 'events' was added for $(el).
        // Let's find this newly added property using difference between new and old arrays.
        const newJqueryKeys = getPropsByName(el, "jQuery");
        const newJqueryKeysWithEvents = $(newJqueryKeys).not(jqueryKeys).get(0);

        // After we determine new property with 'events'
        // lets merge it into the old one to make Foundation events work as expected.
        $.extend(el[jqueryKeysWithEvents], el[newJqueryKeysWithEvents]);
    });
};
```

Then this:

```
$('#test-slider').on('moved.zf.slider', function () {
    // Do something
});
```

simply can be replaced with this:

```
$('#test-slider').mutatedOn('moved.zf.slider', function () {
    // Do something
});
```